# Is the timestamp of Network Time Protocol(NTP) stamped at Application Layer?

Tags: ntp

NTP is a protocol for clock synchronization between computers in the network. It is based on UDP/IP, but I don't know when the timestamp is stamped. Which layer is it in the Network Architecture?

Comment: The OSI layers are a poor fit for current internet protocols. It doesn't really make that much sense anymore. I would recommend ignoring it. Nobody uses this, textbooks authors just refuse to move on.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. TCP/IP protocol is a widely used model for current network. However, there is also an Application Layer in TCP/IP, right?

Comment: Maybe.. my real point is that the OSI layers were invented for a set of protocols that are no longer in use. If you squint real hard you can kind of make it fit with current protocols but it's a poor abstraction, even more so on the higher layers. My advice is forget about the OSI model. It's not relevant anymore.

Comment: Certainly, I know what you are talking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  There are four layers in the tcp/ip model: network access, internet, transport, and application.  For NTP, network access usually is ethernet, internet is IPv4 or IPv6, transport is UDP, and application is NTP itself.  So, based on this, I you could say the timestamp is stamped by the application.